# install mysql 8.0.17 ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql

I need mysql 8.0.17 on ubuntu 18.04.

I downloaded their archive mysql file mysql-server_8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb-bundle.tar
(https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/)

and tried to install it according to the instruction https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/linux-installation-debian.html

when running

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-{common, community-client, client, community-server, server}_*.deb
```

i got errors

```
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 227920 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-common_8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack mysql-community-client_8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-client (8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04) over (8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client.
Preparing to unpack mysql-client_8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client (8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack mysql-community-server_8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
install: invalid user ‘mysql’
dpkg: error processing archive mysql-community-server_8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb (--install):
 new mysql-community-server package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack mysql-server_8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mysql-common (8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Setting up mysql-community-client (8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mysql-client (8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server_8.0.17-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
 mysql-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. First you need to uninstall anything that is related to mysql.

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Next thing is to upgrade your distro.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now after this is done, you can try to install mysql as normal again.